# Improve Listbox item range selection

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, listbox

I have a Listbox with around 100 items, and a Checkbox to select/unselect all items, in a WindowsForms.

When I select all the items the program turns slow until the loop has selected every item , it costs 4-5 seconds to select all the items, the selection is really very slow (I have a good machine and I've tested it into a test project, just the own Listbox control is slow to select items)

```
If Not ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count = ListBox1.Items.Count Then
    For item As Integer = 0 To Me.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        ListBox1.SetSelected(item, True)
    Next
End If
```

Exist any technique to improve this item selection on the control?

I've tried to disable drawing on the control when selecting the items but it wastes the same 4-5 times to select all the items...

Also I don't consider the option to create a new thread only to select the items of a control for two reasons, 1. it will takes the same amount of time to update the control, 2. is not very elegant to create it just fo select a small amount of items in a control...

Comment: What did you try to disable the drawing on the list box control? It would be helpful to actually put the code you tried, instead of just saying I tried something and it was still slow.

Comment: On my question you can see the code that I'm using right now, the drawing things what I've tested time ago so I've deleted the code because doesn't worked, I don't have that code, but I just thought that disabling drawing on the control (disable paintng events also) could accelerate the Listbox's slow logic to accelerate the item selection.

Comment: Is this listbox bound to data? Are you doing something in the class/property it is bound to that takes a while? If so, you need to speed up that code some how. If not, well, you need a new computer because this must be a **IBM 5150** if it takes 4-5 seconds.

Comment: nope, the listbox has simply strings. I've tested it with a "test" project (an empty UI), please try to add 100 items to listbox, then try to use a loop to check/uncheck all you you will see what I mean... it will take much seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` around the loop that selects the items, like this:

```
If Not ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count = ListBox1.Items.Count Then
    ' Stop the ListBox from drawing while items are added.
    ListBox1.BeginUpdate()

    For item As Integer = 0 To Me.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        ListBox1.SetSelected(item, True)
    Next

    ' End the update process and force a repaint of the ListBox.
    ListBox1.EndUpdate()
End If
```

---

Read [BeginUpdate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.beginupdate.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) and [EndUpdate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.endupdate.aspx) documentation for more information.

Comment: Hi, I still have the problem, beginupdate/endupdate was one of those things that I've tried to do to gain speed on Listbox's Logic but... no way.

Answer (score 0):

There are built-in functions to select and unselect all items. I think they're pretty fast. So you could try this in your event handler...

myListBox.SelectAll();
OR
myListBox.UnselectAll();